# App crash running OpenCV apps in Android Emulator

Tags: android, opencv, android-emulator

I'm trying to use some emulators to run my apps for debugging. This app runs perfectly on my phone, but when I load it up into the emulator it crashes whenever I invoke an opencv function. The emulator is using the intel atom x86 cpu. Do I have to run them with the arm7?

Stack trace:

```
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.uas.Processor.extract(Processor.java:48)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.uas.ImageProcessorActivity.onMenuItemClick(ImageProcessorActivity.java:626)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.widget.PopupMenu.onMenuItemSelected(PopupMenu.java:142)
   02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.uas-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.uas-1]: findLibrary returned null
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.<clinit>(Mat.java:2065)
    02-13 04:25:51.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: If you're running this with an intel x86 emulator you need to make sure you're using the x86 version of the SDK.

Comment: are you linking the openCV library asynchronously or statically through your code..?